# (Vue.js) Icon does not apply

Tags: html, vue.js, icons

```
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/static/icons/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/static/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

[My sourse](https://github.com/Sh031224/portfolio)

AND 
[Site link](https://sh031224.github.io/portfolio/)

The icon does not apply. How can i do?

Comment: So is it a favicon you need, or the icon if an iPhone saves the websites to its frontpage ?

Comment: I need a favicon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `/` in front of your image urls:

Use the following `href`s, and it should work.

```
<link rel="icon" href="static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="static/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="static/icons/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="static/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: @Sh031224 You're welcome. Remember to mark the answer as correct.